# google maps not displaying

Tags: android-emulator

In my application I want to display the maps. But its not displaying i don't know why it behaves.

Actually first I got the API by running `cmd` in `cmd prompt` like this. First I went to the

```
c:\program files\java\jdk1.6.0\bin>keytool.exe -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\.android\debug.keystore" -storepass android -keypass android
```

Enter this cmd. I got md5 finger print like this

```
androiddebugkey, Jun 21, 2011, PrivateKeyEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (MD5): 87:A0:E9:D4:D6:C8:B1:E6:AB:D1:AD:DE:A7:03:B1:7F
```

So I have to copy this one into the http://code.google.com/android/maps-api-signup.html and i got this API `00FpJatadwKOTgrosangJKa0bxxbHJBAUB_GyBA`. I put this into the xml like this

```
<com.google.android.maps.MapView 
    android:id="@+id/mapView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:apiKey="00FpJatadwKOTgrosangJKa0bxxbHJBAUB_GyBA"
    />
```

And my java file is following package

```
com.orb.google;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;

public class GoogleActivity extends MapActivity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}
}
```

And also my manifest file is like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.orb.google"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" />

<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" /> 
    <activity android:name=".GoogleActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
</manifest>
```

So please help me why I cannot get the Google Maps in my emulator there is no error getting in console and logcat files.and also already developed application that it displays the maps in another system it cannot display the maps in my system.what is the problem please help me.thanks advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the googleApi emulator if you are not using this.